# Does this program use the Sieve of Eratosthenes?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment as follows,
:  Use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to locate and print out all prime numbers from 1 to 1000.

Follow a procedure similar to this:

1. Write down, in order, all number to be considered.
2. Cross out 1, since it is not considered prime.
3. Go to the next number not crossed out; leave it, but cross out all multiples of that number.
4. Repeat step 3 until you pas the number which is half of the largest number considered. At that point, all numbers not crossed out are the desired primes.

Your algorithm may vary slightly from the one above but speed is important.

I wrote this program out using the knowledge I have of math and arrays however as I was researching Sieve, I had no clue if this was the method.

```
public class PrimeSieve
 {

     public static void main( String[] args) 
     { 
         int max=1000;
         calcPrimes( max ); 
        } 

        public static void calcPrimes( int max ) 
        { 
            // each boolean value indicates whether corresponding index 
            // position is composite (non-prime) 
            boolean[] array = new boolean[max +1 ]; 

            // mark composites as true 
             for (int i = 2; i <= (int) Math.sqrt( max ); i++) 
             {
                 for (int j = i*i; j <= max; j += i) array [j ] = true; 
                 {

             // print indexes with corresponding false values 
                    for (int k = 2;k <= max; k++) 
                    {

                        if ( !array[ k ] ) 
                        System.out.format( k + "\n" ); 
                    }

                }
            }
      } 
}
```

Any help would be nice!

Comment: how so? Can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: and why did you vote my question down? I thought it a pretty valid question and if I am voted I cant ask anymore should a problem arise

Comment: And how dare you assume it was me?

Comment: It simply declares values to true within the array.

Comment: Oh sorry Marko I just assumed it was you because your the only one on. But anyways I started from the square because 2 and 3 are prime while 4 is not and i begins ar 2. The program prints out the primes properly, I just dont know if it is sieve or not.

Comment: Starting from the square is fine. You can also advance by `2*i` instead of just `i`. However, there's something funny about your `for` loop that is followed by **both** a statement and a block. It doesn't do what the formatting would suggest.

Comment: The program is definitely not correct. All it does is print 2 followed by all the odd numbers.

Comment: Is it the continue until half the numbers passed? See I was confused by that.

Comment: @daborn Can you explain why is it correct to start from the square of the number instead of the first multiple, as the assignment you posted proposes? Also why is it correct to stop at the square root of the array size? I must say I doubt your assertion that you wrote this using your knowledge of math and arrays---especially since it so obviously does not print the prime numbers.

Comment: As stated above, the reason I start at the square is because 2 and 3 are in fact prime numbers, so I need to begin the search at 4. I stop at the square root because I am squaring prior

Comment: To see that it is correct to start at the square of the number, consider the case where we have marked off 2s, 3s, and 5s, and are about to mark off 7s. We need not mark off 14, because we would have done that when we did the 2s, or 21, which we would have marked off with the 3s. The 2s got 28, and the 5s just got 35. The 2s eliminated 42. Thus, the first multiple of 7 we could possibly need to mark off is 49.

Comment: We can stop at the square root of max because for any number `i`, the first thing we would do is square it. Thus, if the square of it is larger than max, there would be no numbers struck off because of it. I assure you, Marko, these are well-known optimizations of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: Mr. Conrad explained it much better than I. I apoligize for confusing you marko. I am just a noob and in my head things make sense but explaining them is difficult. These methods were discussed in videos for my class.

Comment: @DavidConrad I was questioning OP's assertion, not asking for my sake.  Here's my assesment: OP found a piece of code but, lacking enough knowledge or interest in the subject, was unable to ascertain whether it implements the sieve. He also found another piece of code which "prints the array" but, lacking enough knowledge of loops and arrays,  did not correctly merge it into the first piece of code. He didn't however notice this, being sure that the code was actually correct. Then he came here to ask whether this is the sieve at all before he submits his work.

Comment: And the valuable lesson OP learned is that the only skills you need in life are people skills. The world is full of well-intended experts whom you can sweet-talk into doing the work you take credit for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do not complete the process of marking off composites before printing out the results, possibly because your loops are nested in a confused sort of way.

```
public static void calcPrimes(int max) {
    // each boolean value indicates whether corresponding index
    // position is composite (non-prime)
    boolean[] array = new boolean[max + 1];

    // mark composites as true
    for (int i = 2; i <= (int) Math.sqrt(max); i++) {
        for (int j = i*i; j <= max; j += i) array[j] = true;
    }

    // print indexes with corresponding false values
    for (int k = 2; k <= max; k++) {
        if (!array[k]) System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

In this example, I have moved the code to print the primes outside of the loop that performs the sieve.

Comment: Oh okay that looks alot better than mine and operates better. What made that completing the sieve though? Is it because yours marked through better than mine?

Comment: It is because it does not print any results until after all of the "mark composites as true" work has been completed.

Comment: Okay thank you so much that makes sense. It is funny how simply moving stuff around works!